# conditional sql query for tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have to run a query from SQL. Perhaps too easy or not, but unfortunately I do not understand SQL. So here's my tables:

**films**

```
id | movie_name
------------
1  | prometheus
```

**names**

```
id | person_name
-----------------
1  | Ridley Scott
2  | Noomi Rapace
3  | Michael Fassbender
4  | Charlize Theron
5  | Damon Lindelof
```

**films_cast**

```
id | film_id | person_id | type
-------------------------------
1  | 1       | 1         | director
2  | 1       | 2         | actor
3  | 1       | 3         | actor
4  | 1       | 4         | actor
5  | 1       | 5         | writer
```

And how can I reach such a conclusion from these tables:

**film_archive**

```
id | movie_name | director     | writer         | cast
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | prometheus | Ridley Scott | Damon Lindelof | Noomi Rapace, Michael Fassbender, Charlize Theron
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You need to [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) your tables, then group by film performing [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregation on the names column given a suitable condition:

```sql
SELECT   f.id,
         f.movie_name,
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF(c.type='director', n.person_name, NULL)) AS director,
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF(c.type='writer',   n.person_name, NULL)) AS writer,
         GROUP_CONCAT(IF(c.type='actor',    n.person_name, NULL)) AS cast
FROM     films f LEFT JOIN films_cast c ON c.film_id   = f.id
                 LEFT JOIN names n      ON c.person_id = n.id
GROUP BY f.id
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f0dd/3/0).

Comment: You did this much faster than I could!

Comment: How do I export this results into a CSV/TXT file?

Comment: @jeangrey: Before the `FROM` clause, add `INTO OUTFILE '/path/to/file.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you also have the `sql-server` tag on your question, unfortunately sql-server doesn't have `GROUP_CONCAT`, an alternative like [FOR XML / STUFF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-ms-sql-server-2005) is needed:

```
SELECT f.id, f.movie_name,
       STUFF((SELECT ',' + p.person_name
              FROM persons p 
                INNER JOIN films_cast fc on fc.person_id = p.id
                WHERE fc.film_id = f.id AND fc.type = 'director'
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') AS director,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + p.person_name
              FROM persons p 
                INNER JOIN films_cast fc on fc.person_id = p.id
                WHERE fc.film_id = f.id AND fc.type = 'writer'
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') AS writer,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + p.person_name
              FROM persons p 
                INNER JOIN films_cast fc on fc.person_id = p.id
                WHERE fc.film_id = f.id AND fc.type = 'actor'
              FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '') AS cast
    FROM films f;
```

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1cd1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT      a.id, a.movie_name,
            GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN b.type = 'director' THEN c.person_name ELSE NULL END)) as `director`,
            GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN b.type = 'writer' THEN c.person_name ELSE NULL END)) as `writer`,
            GROUP_CONCAT((CASE WHEN b.type = 'actor' THEN c.person_name ELSE NULL END)) as `cast`
FROM        films a
            LEFT JOIN film_cast b
                ON a.id = b.film_id
            LEFT JOIN names c
                ON b.person_id = c.id
GROUP BY    a.id, a.movie_name
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f0dd/2)